# how to convert while loop into a function or procedure and pass in new parameters python

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

```
Motorbike_price = 3000

print("£",Motorbike_price)

while Motorbike_price > 1000:
    Motorbike_price = Motorbike_price * 0.9
    print("£",Motorbike_price)
```

> how to convert while loop into a function or procedure and pass in new parameters python

Comment: Just move that code into a function which has `Motorbike_price` as a parameter. What more is there to it?

Comment: Do you also need to make `1000` and `0.9` parameters? Just add more variables for them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: maybe it would be better to get some tutorial and learn how to create function - you wouldn't have to wait for answer(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, it would be better to get some tutorial to learn basis like functions.

```
def my_function(price):
    while price > 1000:
        price = price * 0.9
        print("£", price)
```

and don't forget to run it

```
my_function(Motorbike_price)
```